# Unable to create a pool with custom images on MS Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to create a pool of virtual machines built on my custom image. I've successfully [created a custom image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/capture-image) and added it to my batch account.

But when I try to create a pool, based on this image from the azure portal, I get an error.

> There was an error encountered while performing the last resize on the
>   pool. Please try resizing the pool again. Code: AllocationFailed
>
> Message: Desired number of dedicated nodes could not be allocated
>
> Details: Reason - The source managed disk or snapshot associated with
>   the virtual machine Image Id was not found.

While creating a pool in the portal I use my image name, as there's no option to set an image id. But the image Id in the json is correct. And I can see the image listed in the portal in the correct batch account.

Here's my pool properties json:

```
{
  "id": "my-pool-0",
  "displayName": "my-pool-0",
  "lastModified": "2018-12-04T15:54:06.467Z",
  "creationTime": "2018-12-04T15:44:18.197Z",
  "state": "active",
  "stateTransitionTime": "2018-12-04T15:44:18.197Z",
  "allocationState": "steady",
  "allocationStateTransitionTime": "2018-12-04T16:09:11.667Z",
  "vmSize": "standard_a2",
  "resizeTimeout": "PT15M",
  "currentDedicatedNodes": 0,
  "currentLowPriorityNodes": 0,
  "targetDedicatedNodes": 1,
  "targetLowPriorityNodes": 0,
  "enableAutoScale": false,
  "autoScaleFormula": null,
  "autoScaleEvaluationInterval": null,
  "enableInterNodeCommunication": false,
  "maxTasksPerNode": 1,
  "url": "https://mybatch.westeurope.batch.azure.com/pools/my-pool-0",
  "resizeErrors": [
    {
      "message": "Desired number of dedicated nodes could not be allocated",
      "code": "AllocationFailed",
      "values": [
        {
          "name": "Reason",
          "value": "The source managed disk or snapshot associated with the virtual machine Image Id was not found."
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "virtualMachineConfiguration": {
    "imageReference": {
      "publisher": null,
      "offer": null,
      "sku": null,
      "version": null,
      "virtualMachineImageId": "/subscriptions/79b59716-301e-401a-bb8b-22edg5c1he4j/resourceGroups/resource-group-1/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/my-image"
    },
    "nodeAgentSKUId": "batch.node.ubuntu 18.04"
  },
  "applicationLicenses": null
}
```

It seems like the error text has nothing to do with what actually is wrong. Has anyone encountered this error or now a way to troubleshoot this?

**UPDATE**

Packer json used to create the image ([taken from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/build-image-with-packer))

```
{
  "builders": [{
    "type": "azure-arm",

    "client_id": "ffxcvbd0-c867-429a-bxcv-8ee0acvb6f99",
    "client_secret": "cvb54cvb-202d-4wq-bb8b-22cdfbce4f",
    "tenant_id": "ae33sdfd-a54c-40af-b20c-80810f0ff5da",
    "subscription_id": "096da34-4604-4bcb-85ae-2afsdf22192b",

    "managed_image_resource_group_name": "resource-group-1",
    "managed_image_name": "my-image",

    "os_type": "Linux",
    "image_publisher": "Canonical",
    "image_offer": "UbuntuServer",
    "image_sku": "18.04-LTS",

    "azure_tags": {
        "dept": "Engineering",
        "task": "Image deployment"
    },

    "location": "West Europe",
    "vm_size": "Standard_DS2_v2"
  }],
  "provisioners": [{
    "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; {{ .Vars }} sudo -E sh '{{ .Path }}'",
    "inline": [
      "export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive",
      "apt-get update",
      "apt-get upgrade -y",
      "apt-get -y install nginx",

        ... 

      "/usr/sbin/waagent -force -deprovision+user && export HISTSIZE=0 && sync"
    ],
    "inline_shebang": "/bin/sh -x",
    "type": "shell"
  }]
}
```

Comment: What format are you storing the image in, Managed Disk, Snapshot, Managed Image or are you using the new shared image gallery?

Comment: @SamCogan I believe it's a managed disk, I created it with packer as per docs. And it's under Home - Images.

Comment: ok, if it's been created with Packer it will be a managed disk image

Comment: @sr9yar If the answer is helpful you can accept it.

Comment: @CharlesXu np, I was going to test it as well, as we're going to move to a paid subscription one of these days, but I think your answer is correct, since I didn't create a VHD, I was creating an image directly with packer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your issue, I did the test as you. The steps here:

1. Create the managed image through Packer.
2. Create the Batch Pool with the managed image in the same subscription and region.

And then I get the same error as you. Then I make another test that creates the image from a snapshot and then create the Batch Pool with the image. Luck! The pool works well.

> In Azure you can prepare a managed image from snapshots of an Azure
>   VM's OS and data disks, from a generalized Azure VM with managed
>   disks, or from a generalized on-premises VHD that you upload.

Reference to this [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-custom-images#prepare-a-custom-image), it seems the custom image cannot create through Packer. I'm not sure about this. But it really works. Hope this will help you.

**Update**

Take a look at the document [Custom Images with Batch Shipyard](https://github.com/Azure/batch-shipyard/blob/master/docs/63-batch-shipyard-custom-images.md#provision). The description:

> Note: Currently creating an ARM Image directly with Packer can only be
>   used with User Subscription Batch accounts. For standard Batch Service
>   pool allocation mode Batch accounts, Packer will need to create a VHD
>   first, then you will need to import the VHD to an ARM Image. Please
>   follow the appropriate path that matches your Batch account pool
>   allocation mode.

In my test, I have followed the steps that Packer does to create the image. When the source VM exists, the custom image can be used normally for Batch Pool. But it will fail if you delete the source VM. So, as the description, the standard Batch Service just can use the image created from VHD file that Packer create and the VHD file should exist in the Pool lifetime.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. I've read the page you referenced so many times, that I almost remember this by heart xD At the moment I ended up creating a pool of standard ubuntu images, then logging in each vm and installing software I need manually. But this not what I need, since I already have my own pool of vps servers and I'm looking for a better way to manage them with a CLI tool.  I'm guessing, something else must be installed in the image during packer build to make this image a valid Azure VM image. But that's just a wild guess.

Comment: Yeah, I will also try to confirm about this. If the image needs something specific.

Answer (score 0):

If your using a managed image then your imageReference section should look like this:

`"imageReference": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/79b59716-301e-401a-bb8b-22edg5c1he4j/resourceGroups/resource-group-1/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/my-image"
    },`

Comment: ok, but I downloaded this pool properties json from the portal, and it contains 'virtualMachineImageId'. I didn't write it myself. Do you suggest changing this attribute and re-creating the pool via json ?

Comment: Let’s take a step back, how are you creating the scaleset in the first place? ARM, CLI?

Comment: My initial goal was to be able to create everything with CLI. But `az batch pool create` gave me an error, something about using the sharedkey, so switched to simply using the web interface at portal.azure.com - the ARM, right? The terminology already tricked me a couple of times today :(